# I need to create a regular expression only for whole numbers with thousands separator

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying the following way in vue:

```
<v-text-field
   v-model="value"  
   v-mask="[/\d/,/\d/,'.',/\d/,/\d/,/\d/,'.',/\d/,/\d/,/\d/]"
/>
```

By entering 5123456 Sample 51.234.56, I need you to show 5.123.456